# How can I align a widget in a column

Tags: flutter, dart, flexbox, flutter-layout

[image]

How can I align a widget in a column,  it's complex to describe, please read the code in the pic,

part of the code

```
              Row(children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ColoredBox(
                  color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                  child: Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.amberAccent,
                      width: 130,
                      height: 130,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                        child: ColoredBox(
                            color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                            child: ConstrainedBox(
                                constraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: 130, maxHeight: double.infinity),
                                child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: const [
                                  Text(
                                    "this line might have lots of letters, it will expend the `deepPurpleAccent` row's height",
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                                  ),
                                  Text("this line should align to the bottom of the left amberAccent Container or under it")
                                ]))))
                  ])),
            )
          ]),
```

Comment: Avoid posting code-image, provide code snippet instead. More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: it is solved now,  see the answer blow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add mainAxisAlignment property in your Column Widget. Like this:

```
    Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: const [
                Text("this line might have lots of letters, it will expend the `deepPurpleAccent` row's height",
                 style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                ),
                Text("this line should align to the bottom of the left amberAccent Container or under it")
    ],
   ),
```